# Looping through tables with Oracle Subqueries

Tags: oracle

I want to run an Oracle validation function against every table in the database that has a suitable column.
The validation can be run against one table simply:

```
SELECT
count (*)
FROM
Table_name t
Where
SDO_GEOM.VALIDATE_GEOMETRY_WITH_CONTEXT(t.Column_name, 0.005) <> 'TRUE';
```

This works fine for an individual table, but as there are over 100 to test I wanted to merge it with the Oracle Metadata table using a subquery and thus automate the whole thing. I've come up with two variants but neither works, I guess because it's having trouble passing variables from inside the subquery.
My two attempts are:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME tab, COLUMN_NAME col, (select count(*) from tab where sdo_geom.validate_geometry(tab.col, 0.005) <> 'TRUE')
From
All_Tab_Columns
where 
owner = 'WCCDATA' and DATA_TYPE = 'SDO_GEOMETRY'
```

Which returns:

SQL Error: ORA-00904: "TAB"."COL": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

and

```
SELECT count(*)
From 
(SELECT
TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME as col
FROM
All_Tab_Columns
where 
owner = 'WCCDATA' and DATA_TYPE = 'SDO_GEOMETRY') subquery
WHERE sdo_geom.validate_geometry(subquery.col, 0.005) <> 'TRUE';
```

which returns:

ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOM", line 2204
00942. 00000 -  "table or view does not exist"

Anyone have any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You can't ever reference column values as identifiers (tables, columns, etc.).  In order to do this, you'll need to write some PL/SQL to create and execute the SQL dynamically, perhaps like this:

```
DECLARE
   CURSOR cur_tables IS
      SELECT   table_name,
                  'SELECT count(*) From '
               || table_name
               || ' WHERE sdo_geom.validate_geometry('
               || column_name
               || ', 0.005) <> ''TRUE'''
                  AS dsql
        FROM   all_tab_columns
       WHERE   owner = 'WCCDATA' AND data_type = 'SDO_GEOMETRY';
   v_count   NUMBER;
BEGIN
   FOR r_tables IN cur_tables LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE r_tables.dsql INTO   v_count;

      DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(r_tables.table_name || ': ' || v_count);
   END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Thanks Allan, I've never even looked at PL/SQL before so that's entirely new to me. When I try and run it in Oracle SQL Developer however it doesn't work and I get the error: `code`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
ORA-06512: at line 15
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"`code` Any ideas?

Comment: @Jonathan: The PL/SQL block works fine for me, so I think it's got to be the SQL constructed in the query (which makes sense, as line 15 is the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` command).  Try running the query separately and running one or two of the SQL statements it produces.  The other possibility is that the blank line is throwing off SQL Developer (I'm not familiar enough with it to know if that's likely).

Comment: Sorry but no joy. Per your suggestions, I've run the `Select` in the `DECLARE` and it's fine on it's own and so are the the `selects` that it creates. I don't know how to run only the PL/SQL, but I did manage to (eventually) figure out how to run it using SQLPlus (from a separate machine), but that gives the exact same errors as SQL Developer does (00933 and 06512 at line 15). Also tried with the blank line removed, but to no effect. Our Oracle is 10.2.0.4 if that makes a difference.

Comment: Try running the PL/SQL block with output on (`set serveroutput on;` before the code above).  If you get some results, that may indicate that some of the SQL works, just not all of it. It's definitely not SQL Developer (I checked out that possibility as well) and it shouldn't be a version problem.

Comment: That let me figure it out. It was selecting all table names, including the "junk" tables that various applications have created (i.e. _BIN$pb1YwZ6b21DgQEwKIHAqJQ==$0_, or _MDRT_169B0$_ ). I've fixed this by adding some more clauses to your `WHERE   owner = 'WCCDATA' AND data_type = 'SDO_GEOMETRY';` - the result of that line then becomes `Where   Owner = 'WCCDATA' And Data_Type = 'SDO_GEOMETRY' And Table_Name Not Like 'BIN$%' And Table_Name Not Like 'MDRT_%' And Not Regexp_Like(Table_Name, 'N_[0-9]+_.*') And Not Regexp_Like(Table_Name, '[A-Z][0-9]');` - This works now. Thanks!